# How to seconds to Time using calendar and passing the values back to the function

Tags: java, algorithm, calendar

My scenario is to create time in a particular pattern

For ex : startTime and duration will be entered by the user.

let startTime be 9:00:00 and duration is 60s. Now my output should be like add up 60sec to my starttime and set that as end time. Then add 10mins to startTime and again add 60s to it and set it as endtime. this will be iterated within a loop.

I have done somepart of that work and i got partial output, 
THe output is got is like

```
startTime : 9:00:00
EndTime   : 9:01:00
startTime : 9:00:00
EndTime   : 9:01:00
startTime : 9:00:00
EndTime   : 9:01:00
```

But the expected output is like

```
startTime : 9:00:00
EndTime   : 9:01:00
startTime : 9:11:00 // HERE ADDING 10mins to startTime and assigning it as startTime again
EndTime   : 9:12:00 // Adding 60sec duration to the updated startTime
startTime : 9:20:00
EndTime   : 9:21:00
```

My code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String myTime = "090000";
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");
             Date d = df.parse(myTime); 
             Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
             cal.setTime(d);
             cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 60);
             String newTime = df.format(cal.getTime());
             System.out.println("Start time : "+myTime);
             System.out.println("end Time   :"+newTime);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the 10 minutes at the end of the loop. (Also, you don't need to create the SimpleDateFormat in every loop).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");
    String myTime = "090000";
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        Date d = df.parse(myTime); 
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(d);
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 60);
        String newTime = df.format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println("Start time : "+myTime);
        System.out.println("end Time   :"+newTime);

        // now add 10 minutes to the start time
        cal.setTime(d);
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
        myTime = df.format(cal.getTime());
    }
}
```